# I have only one scanner installed. But Ubuntu shows two

Tags: scanner

I have only an HP Deskjet 2540 installed in Ubuntu 16.04. But in scanner, it shows two devices

For example, when I start Xsane  it shows two available devices.[image: screenshot]

The device is connected via wifi only. Both scanners are shown only when connected to the same wifi. Only one printer (the first one hp:/net/Deskjet_2540_series?zc=HP9CB654E780ED) is shown in system setting / printers. I can delete only that from system setting / printers. Can't delete the duplicate.

How to delete the duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only one device, but accessing via two different methods. I presume this device is connected to your network for printing and scanning, as well as connected to your computer via USB. The second entry in that list is for accessing the device over the network (see the `ip=192.168.1.104` bit.

To get rid of one of the entries, you can either disconnect it from your PC directly, and scan over network, or disconnect it from the network and only scan over USB. Or leave it as is, and do either.

Comment: The printer is connected via wifi only. Both are shown only when connected to the same wifi. Only one printer (the first one hp:/net/Deskjet_2540_series?zc=HP9CB654E780ED) is shown in system setting / printers. I can delete only that from system setting / printers. Can't delete the duplicate